# Erro ao tentar acessar a minha API

Tags: javascript, c#, api, aplicação-web

Estou tentando acessar no frontend uma api simples que desenvolvi, mas está dando esse erro: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:5001/funcionario' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource". A API é em C# e o front estou desenvolvendo em js puro.

O código do front:

```
function fazGet(url){
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open("GET", url, false);
    request.send();
    return request.responseText
}

function criaLinha(usuario){

}

function Main(){
    const data = fazGet("https://localhost:5001/funcionario");
    const funcionarios = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(funcionarios);
}

Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa habilitar o [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0) na sua API.

É bem simples de se fazer. Na sua API, abra o `Program.cs` e adicione as seguintes linhas:

```
var corsPolicy = "MinhaPoliticaCORS";
builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy(name: "MinhaPoliticaCORS",
                      policy => {
                          policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7263");
                      });
});
```

O endereço `https://localhost:7263` é o endereço do seu frontend (que está consumindo a API).

Por último, ainda no arquivo `Program.cs` da sua API, basta adicionar o middleware CORS. A chamada `app.UseCors(corsPolicy)` deve ser feita depois de `UseRouting` e antes de `UseAuthorization`:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors(corsPolicy);
app.UseAuthorization();
```

O exemplo acima foi feito em um ASP.NET Core 6.